# File path in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, path, directory, root

Im having a hard time with a link to a video file in one of my CI views.

Videos folder is in CodeIgniter root directory. When I link the video file name as following, everything works fine.

```
<source type="video/mp4" src="/videos/<?= $video->filename ?>" />
```

But I need to be able to link a file, that is outside of CI root folder, for example somewhere else on C disk, like C:/videos. Cant figure out how to do it. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Ill be a little bit more specific.

My codeigniter app will be placed on a server in WEB directory:

```
/something1/something2/web/
```

Now Video Files folder will be placed on a same level as WEB folder:

```
/something1/something2/videos/
```

I want to link videos that are in Videos folder, which is on a same level as WEB(CI root) folder.

Comment: Why would you link to something like `c:\videos`? This may work on your machine, but not everyone got a `c:\videos` directory on their machine.

Answer (score 1):

If your videos folder is outside your CI-install, you could set the video dir as a config item in `/config/config.php`:

```
$config['video_dir'] = 'http://example.com/videos';
```

You can then retrieve it in your controller like this:

```
$data['video_dir'] = $this->config->item('video_dir');
```

(Or you could just have a videos folder inside the CI directory...)

Answer (score 0):

Try It

`<source type="video/mp4" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>videos/<?= $video->filename ?>" />`